# Copying a rectangular selection to system clipboard

Tags: copy-paste, kill-ring, clipboard, rectangle

Does anyone know a command or somtething to copy an rectangular selection (as with C-x r M-w / copy-rectange-as-kill) and put the killed rectangle into the system clipboard like with the kill-ring-save command ?

I would something like :
1) copy the rectangle region
2) paste the rectangle in a temporary buffer
3) delete the trailing whitespaces
3) copy the buffer's content to system clipboard but not in the kill-ring (don't mess with the kill-ring)
4) delete the temporary buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun copy-rectangle-to-system-clipboard (start end)
  "Like `copy-rectangle-as-kill', but also copy to system clipboard."
  (interactive "r")
  (call-interactively #'copy-rectangle-as-kill)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (yank-rectangle)
    (delete-trailing-whitespace)
    (funcall interprogram-cut-function (buffer-string))))
```

I have tested it using graphical Emacs 25.2 on macOS.

Comment: FYI, `(kill-new (buffer-string))` worked for me, but `(funcall interprogram-cut-function (buffer-string))` does not.  Emacs version: 28.1

Answer (score 0):

Apart from deleting trailing whitespace, you get all you need with built-in CUA minor mode. Set it permanently with `(cua-mode t)` in your emacs config or toggle it interactively. Press `C-<Return>` to enter rectangle editing, use arrow keys to select the area, and copy it to kill-ring and system clipboard with `C-c`.

If you do a lot of copying and pasting, have a look at `counsel-yank-pop` (part of abo-abo's ivy/councel/swiper) that gives you an easy access to emacs kill-ring history. I've bound it to `M-y`. It makes it convenient to copy several chunks of text from your source and paste them one by one to your target document.